# Export Jupyter notebook without codes

Tags: jupyter-notebook, export-to-pdf

Is there any way to export Jupyter notebook as PDF without codes,but only charts .
I tried Save as HTML , but then couldn't delete the cells with codes.

Is there any suggestion how delete code cells from HTML or export notebook  without codes ?

Answer (score 1):

1st install 'texlive-xetex'
then convert it using 'nbconvert'

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf test.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf code.ipynb
```